# jQuery changing value , binding in database with ajax Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

my situation is : When I click to my StatusCheck (it has 0 value) link image , when i click i need that value to be 1  ant it will change in my database table form 0 to 1 ..., i know that this thing does with ajax , how can i do this?

here is my code

```
               $(function() {
          $('.imageCheck').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
          $(this).find("#bg").attr('src',"/application/admin/img/tick.png");  

         var image_id = $('#bg').attr('image_id');

           $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "content_users_blog.php",
         data: {image_id: image_id},
         success:
             function(data){
                data();
                 $('#bg').attr('value', '1');
            }
     });
   });
});    

</script>  
<th>Status</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            foreach ($users as $user):

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$user['id']?></td>
                <td>                                                      
<div class="imageCheck"><img id="bg" src="<?php echo $img_path;?>publish_x.png"  
 name="statusCheck" value="0" />

    </div>                                                     
                                        </td>
```

Comment: I guess you are sending your ajax with $_GET instead of $_POST.Either change code in content_users_blog.php to work with $_POST or send some code where you check values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would first need to create a PHP page that increments the value in the database. You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$db = mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET statuscheck=1 WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Then you would need to load this page to make the change happen. You could tie this functionality to a button or something like this:

```
function updateStatus(eID) {
$.ajax({
       url: 'updatestatus.php?id='+eID,
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
            // page loaded successfully, do any additionally coding here
       }
    });
} // end function
```

Then just tie this function to a button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Update Status" onclick="updateStatus(1);" />
```

When the button is clicked, the entry with the ID of 1 will be updated in the database.

Comment: can i use here my jquery function for click on the image , to load value 1 ? thanks for reply

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever function you like. Just make sure you are loading the PHP page which updates the values in the database because you do not want to connect to a database using javascript for security reasons.

Comment: How can i put ca condition something like : if button is clicked and changed the image , than bind value 1 to database to

Comment: bind value 1 to status in  database for the user id that i have ?

Comment: You would just use your user ID variable in place of the ID variable I used. But it's hard to give an exact solution without seeing all the code. If you want me to help you fix it please send me a message through my contact form on my website and I'd be happy to assist you further. You can contact me by clicking on the contact box at the top of the page at http://mdl.fm